# i write like this, but still got the error "A connection to XXX was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body? "

Tags: java, okhttp

I don't know how to avoid it, i have closed the response body already!

Can someone help me solve this problem?

my code:

```
public String getPageFromServer(String activityKey) throws Exception {
    String address = pageServerHolder.getServerAddressRandom();

    String url = MessageFormat.format(URL, address, activityKey);
    log.debug("=============== url [{}] ================", url);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).callTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    final Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).get().build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    try (ResponseBody body = response.body()) {
        if (response.isSuccessful() && null != body) {
            String bodyString = body.string();
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(bodyString)) {
                body.close();
                return bodyString;
            }
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException(MessageFormat.format("获取活动页信息异常，url [{0}], response.code [{1}]，response.message [{2}] ", url, response.code(), response.message()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `Response` is not closed.  Your code should be something like this:

```
try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
     ResponseBody body = response.body()) {
    if (response.isSuccessful() && null != body) {
        String bodyString = body.string();
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(bodyString)) {
            return bodyString;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you *need* to close the `ResponseBody`.  It is possible that closing `response` will deal with it.  However, there is little harm in a redundant close.

---

Check out the example here: https://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: yeah, i know what you mean, but i find the problem like this at [link](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2311) , JakeWharton don't say i should  close the Response but ResponseBody. Moreover, it still warn even i closed the Response.
[here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZyrP.jpg

Answer (score 0):

ResponseBody implements the Closeable interface. You are creating ResponseBody in the resource section of the try block, it will be closed **for you** as you leave the try block.

Your "body.close()" should not be there.

Comment: yeah, you mean i write "body.close()" redundantly, but i still got the warn when i  Comment it out.
[code][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlTf1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
    try (Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
         ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
      if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        log.info("access tree from {} success", url);
        return objectMapper.readValue(responseBody.string(), StorageTreeResponse.class);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
```

I am wondering this is just a bug from okhttp client. Even the `try resource` syntax didn't solve the warnings.